# $q$-analogue of the multinomial theorem?

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, combinatorial-identities, q-analogs, q-identities

The [$q$-binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#q-binomial_theorem) states that
$$
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+q^kt) = \sum_{k=0}^n q^{\binom k2}{n\brack k}_q t^k.
$$
This identity is a $q$-analogue of the binomial theorem
$$
(1+t)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk t^k.
$$

Is there a $q$-analog of the multinomial theorem, or more specifically perhaps a $q$-analogue of the identity
$$
(1 + t + \dotsb + t^{m-1})^n = \sum_{k_1 + \dotsb + k_m = n} \binom n{k_1\;\dotsb\; k_m} t^{k_2 + 2k_3 + \dotsb (m-1)k_m}
$$
where the multinomial coefficients on the right hand side are replaced by their $q$-analogues?

I tried some obvious possibilites for the factors in the LHS, like $(1 + q^it + q^{2i}t^2)$, but this one already fails for $n=2$.

One of the motivations for seeking such a formula is that substitutng $t=-q^{-i}$, for $0\leq i\leq n-1$ in the $q$-binomial theorem gives the identity
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k q^{\binom k2 - ki}{n \brack k}_q = 0,
$$
which in its most famous special case $i=0$ is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k q^{\binom k2}{n\brack k}_q = 0.
$$
I am looking for identities of the form
$$
\sum_{k_1 + \dotsb k_m = n} \zeta^{k_2 + \dotsb + (m-1)k_m} q^?{n \brack k_1\dotsb k_m}_q = 0,
$$
where $\zeta$ stands for a primitive $m$th root of unity, and the "?" may be replaced by an appropriate integer.

Comment: Related? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4005154/the-q-multilinear-theorem

Comment: @FredHucht: These are two different $q$-binomial formulas. For the two-variable case, you can derive the $\prod\left(1+q^k t\right)$-formula from the $ab=qba$-formula (see Exercise A.3.4.14 in [my *An Introduction to Algebraic Combinatorics*](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/21s/lecs.pdf)). For $m$ variables, I'm not sure how to construct $m$ operators that satisfy those $q$-commutativity relations.

Comment: @darijgrinberg This is an interesting approach. One of the difficulties that I face is that I do not know the power of $q$ that should appear on the right hand side. If we do find operators with the necessary commutation relations, then the power of $q$ will come out of their construction.

Comment: May be the section 2 of [this](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/03610926.2020.1737711) paper should help with the formula